# Creating basic functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, integer

I'm new to Haskell and would like a few pointers on creating functions. I am used to writing in C#, Java, and C++, so this stuff is really foreign to me.

Here is the question that I am working on:

> Declare the type and write a function in Haskell that takes three
>   numbers as inputs and returns the larger one. Write two versions of
>   this function: first use if else and second use guards.

In working on the first one I've come up with something like this...:

```
largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int --Declaring type
largestInt a b c = if (a > b && a > c) then a --I don't think this is right, but it's all I have
                   else if (b > a && b > c) then b
                   else c
```

I've been using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XLTRuKoOtM) video for help, but am not able to do the same things as him for some reason. (Meaning that I can't create that Main.hs file)

I am using WinGHCi

I would appreciate it if someone could show me how to setup functions, maybe even this one ^ in Haskell so that I know what I'm doing in the future. Thank you very much.

**Updates:** 
-added `else` to code
-fixed last `if` statement

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: The form for if is `if X then Y else Z`, exactly. You're missing an else clause in the three ifs you have in that snippet.

Comment: Also your type is incorrect -- that's the type of a function that takes two `Int`s and returns an `Int`, you want a function that takes _three_ `Int`s and returns an `Int`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, your third `if` expression is still missing an `else`. (Hint: do you really need the third `if` at all?)

Comment: I guess I wouldn't need the third 'if'. In regards to the type would I put `largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`?

Comment: Yeah, that type looks right.

Comment: When I put that into WinGHCi it gives me the error: `<interactive>:19:1: Not in scope: largestInt`. What is that about?

Comment: Can you post all of your code? (Ie, which line is line 19?)

Comment: When you introduce a new function in `GHCi` you have to bind it with a `let` like: `let f x = x`.

Comment: I think that's irrelevant because I'm using this as the first line of `largestInt`. I just started a new program and made my first line this: `largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`

Comment: In order to define both the function and its type in `GHCi` you still should use `let` like so: `let { largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int; largetInt a b c = head (reverse (sort [a, b, c])) }`

Comment: @Ericafterdark After you create the `.hs` file, you have to load it in GHCi to be able to access the functions in the file. You load it by typing `:load path/to/your/file.hs` and pressing return in GHCi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to J's answer, I've gone ahead and implemented your function. This changes your function to use exhaustive patterns (as J mentioned), and also corrects the type signature, which only accepted 2 Ints. With `if` statements:

```
largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
largestInt a b c = if (a >= b && a >= c) 
                       then a 
                          else if (b >= a && b >= c)
                            then b 
                              else c
```

And with guards (which is a much nicer way to do this, by the way):

```
largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
largestInt a b c
    | (a >= b && a >= c) = a 
    | (b >= a && b >= c) = b
    | otherwise = c
```

If you were to put this directly into GHCI, you would do:

```
{largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int;largestInt a b c ; | (a > b && a > c) = a |(b > a && b > c) = b |otherwise = c}
```

You may need to add semi-colons before each guard, but I believe it doesn't matter. This is the general syntax for defining multi-line functions in GHCI.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. I'm frustrated though because whenever I put in `largestInt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int` I get a `Not in scope: largestInt` error. Is there something that I don't know about?

Comment: Are you putting this directly into GHCI by any chance?

Comment: Yes, into WinGHCi. I added a screenshot

Comment: Yes, I thought so. A better idea is to write a .hs file, and launch it with GHCI. However, if you insist, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: .hs file is fine. But I'm having trouble creating those, like I said in my question -_- Thank you for your help by the way

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. And I'm more than happy to help a fellow student of Haskell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46648/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-azar)

Comment: What if `(a,b,c) = (2,2,1)`? Your function returns `1` in that case, where it should be `2`.

Comment: Sorry Eric, I'm on mobile, and having some technical difficulties. I'd you can wait until tomorrow, I can try to help you then.

Comment: And @amalloy, the question was really asking about the syntax, not the logic. Because of this, I really didn't throughout analyse the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Haskell is an expression and thus must result in a value. The code you wrote involves three "half"-`if`s, none of which resolve to a value. For instance, consider just one "half"-`if`:

```
if (a > b) then c
```

We can replace the `(a > b)` with both `True` and `False` to see what happens. If we use `True` it's clear that the value is

```
if True  then c ====> c
```

But if we use `False`

```
if False then c ====> ?
```

In other words, "half"-`if`s don't make much sense if their condition evaluates to `False`. Thus, in Haskell, all `if`s must be "full" `if`s—i.e. they must always have `then` *and* `else` branches.

```
if (a > b && a > c) 
  then a
  else if (b > a && b > c)
    then b
    else if (c > a && c > b)
      then c
      else ...?
```

Part of the reason Haskell requires "full" `if`s is outlined in this last example—it helps to avoid errors in reasoning like the above where we cannot be certain that the third branch will always be true unless we check it.

In fact, what you've written would have to fall through all the way to the end for something like

```
largestInt 0 0 0
```

Since no argument is *actually* the largest at all!